# Avro deserialization classload issue

Tags: java, deserialization, quarkus, avro

My task is deserialize byte[] to POJO that was serialized with avro schema from json String.

Schema example:

```
"{\"type\":\"record\",\"name\":\"MKB10\",\"namespace\":\"generatedClasses\",\"doc\":\"1.2.643.5.1.13.13.11.1005_2.23\",\"fields\":[{\"name\":\"ID\",\"type\":[\"int\",\"null\"]},{\"name\":\"ACTUAL\",\"type\":[\"int\",\"null\"]},{\"name\":\"MKB_CODE\",\"type\":[\"string\",\"null\"]},{\"name\":\"MKB_NAME\",\"type\":[\"string\",\"null\"]},{\"name\":\"REC_CODE\",\"type\":[\"string\",\"null\"]},{\"name\":\"ID_PARENT\",\"type\":[\"string\",\"null\"]},{\"name\":\"DATE\",\"type\":[\"string\",\"null\"]},{\"name\":\"ADDL_CODE\",\"type\":[\"int\",\"null\"]}]}"
```

Data for serialization saved as string in postgres:

```
{"ID": 3602, "ACTUAL": 1, "MKB_CODE": "H53.2", "MKB_NAME": "\u0414\u0438\u043f\u043b\u043e\u043f\u0438\u044f", "REC_CODE": "0710H532", "ID_PARENT": "3599"}
```

Class for serialize json String data to byte array:

```java
public class JsonAvroSerializer {
    public byte[] jsonAvroSerialize(String jsonString, String schemaString) throws IOException {
        Schema.Parser parser = new Schema.Parser();
        Schema schema = parser.parse(schemaString);

        GenericRecord genericRecord = new GenericData.Record(schema);
        Map<String, Object> jsonData = jsonStringMapper(jsonString);
        jsonData.forEach(genericRecord::put);

        ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        DatumWriter<GenericRecord> datumWriter = new SpecificDatumWriter<>(schema);
        Encoder encoder = EncoderFactory.get().binaryEncoder(outputStream, null);
        datumWriter.write(genericRecord, encoder);
        encoder.flush();

        return outputStream.toByteArray();
    }

    private Map<String, Object> jsonStringMapper(String jsonString) throws IOException {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        return mapper.readValue(jsonString, HashMap.class);
    }
}
```

My POJO for deserialization that I expect (getters/setters omitted):

```java
public class MKB10 {
    private Integer ID;
    private Integer ACTUAL;
    private String MKB_CODE;
    private String MKB_NAME;
    private String REC_CODE;
    private String ID_PARENT;
    private String DATE;
    private Integer ADDL_CODE;
}
```

Deserialization method with hardcoded schema:

```java
    public MKB10 getMkb10(byte[] data ) throws IOException {
        String strJson = "{\"type\":\"record\",\"name\":\"MKB10\",\"namespace\":\"generatedClasses\",\"doc\":\"1.2.643.5.1.13.13.11.1005_2.23\",\"fields\":[{\"name\":\"ID\",\"type\":[\"int\",\"null\"]},{\"name\":\"ACTUAL\",\"type\":[\"int\",\"null\"]},{\"name\":\"MKB_CODE\",\"type\":[\"string\",\"null\"]},{\"name\":\"MKB_NAME\",\"type\":[\"string\",\"null\"]},{\"name\":\"REC_CODE\",\"type\":[\"string\",\"null\"]},{\"name\":\"ID_PARENT\",\"type\":[\"string\",\"null\"]},{\"name\":\"DATE\",\"type\":[\"string\",\"null\"]},{\"name\":\"ADDL_CODE\",\"type\":[\"int\",\"null\"]}]}";
        Schema schema = new Schema.Parser().parse(strJson);

        SpecificDatumReader<MKB10> reader = new SpecificDatumReader<>(schema);
        BinaryDecoder decoder = DecoderFactory.get().binaryDecoder(data, null);

        var mkb10 = reader.read(null, decoder);

        return mkb10;
    }
```

As a result I need to take POJO but have classload Exception:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.apache.avro.generic.GenericData$Record cannot be cast to class api.clients.dictionary.MKB10 (org.apache.avro.generic.GenericData$Record is in unnamed module of loader io.quarkus.bootstrap.classloading.QuarkusClassLoader @6283d8b8; api.clients.dictionary.MKB10 is in unnamed module of loader io.quarkus.bootstrap.classloading.QuarkusClassLoader @77049094)
```

Comment: Make class manually is bad idea when working with avro. Solve it with class generation. https://github.com/davidmc24/gradle-avro-plugin